# Local declaration of 'fieldPhone' hides instance variable

Tags: ios, objective-c

I keep getting the warning that I posted in the title with these methods...I put self. in front of them but it then messed up my menus. I saw some similar posts, but nothing to the point and absolute. Any help on this is appreciated.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)fieldPhone shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSString* totalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",self.fieldPhone.text,string];

    // if it's the phone number textfield format it.
    if(fieldPhone.tag==102 ) {
        if (range.length == 1) {
            // Delete button was hit.. so tell the method to delete the last char.
            fieldPhone.text = [self formatPhoneNumber:totalString deleteLastChar:YES];
        } else {
            fieldPhone.text = [self formatPhoneNumber:totalString deleteLastChar:NO ];
        }
        return false;
    }

    return YES; 
}
```

Comment: Hint: Get rid of the use of any `@synthesize` lines and get rid of any explicit ivar declarations for any of your properties.

Comment: I tried to do that, but I am manipulating that variable in another method when I am calculating user information. Another way?

Comment: When ever you need to access the property, you do `self.propertyName`.

Comment: I did that, but then it overrides my other text fields and makes the code not opperate properly. It works fine with it this way, It just might cause problems submitting to the appstore

Answer (score 0):

Change the function textField name to a generic name, problem is that you named it equal to your class variable, change it from:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)fieldPhone shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
```

to:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
```

You can check it inside the function if needed:

```
if (textField == self.phoneField) {
}
```